# Protected sharing link in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am looking for a way to create and share protected links to a Rails view.

In my application, Users can create project pages. I want to enable Users to create a sharing link, so that only recipients with the link can access the project page and leave comments on that page. I might even want to add password protection to the link.

Is there a gem for that?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I don't know of any gems for protected links and I can imagine that it is hard to find a common denominator for such an individual feature.

However, here's how I would implement such a system. The basic idea is to substitute the id with a practically "unguessable" `token`.

1 - create an `token` column (`index: true`, `unique: true`) for the resource you want to protect

2 - In the model, add validations, generator, callback and override `to_param`

```
validates :token, presence: true
validates :token, uniqueness: true

before_validation :generate_token, on: :create

def generate_token
  begin
    self.token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(64, false)
  end while self.class.find_by(token: token)
end

def to_param
  token
end
```

3 - Change the routes to use `:token` as url parameter

```
resources :things, param: :token
```

4 - Change the controller to find by token instead of id

```
@thing = Thing.find(params[:id])              # change this
@thing = Thing.find_by(token: params[:token]) # to this
```

Now, `thing_url(@thing)` will return a url you can safely share:

```
http://example.com/things/KSwdmTuDSVOGLTHtjK-RU78x7Bme_g-noTrNcovrtXioxPletLvNK35ia_F8CpIBtNDv-_xQ5bZ8uuv18msD4w
```

Of course, you need to replace `thing` and `Thing` with your model name, respectively.

Comment: You're welcome! Btw, added some useful validations which I forgot in my first version... Cheers!

Comment: I implemented this solution and it works! I was wondering: is there also a way to display the normal URL (with /things/id), while redirecting the token URL to /things/id?

Comment: You could set `param: :token_or_id` in routes and then decide what to do in the controller. Basically there are two paths: (a) Find thing by id with `find(...)` then check if user is entitled to access it (b) else find thing by token with `find_by(token: ...)`. However I do not know a way of adding separate url helpers for these cases.