# Rails routes parameters for both :id and :token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

Is it possible to set up a routing parameter for both :id and :token?

There are ample resources out there on how to change the default route params:

```
resources :events, params: :token

def to_param
  token
end
```

However I cant seem to find anything related to an "either or" scenario that would allow someone to access Events#show by either the event_id or the event_token. In my head, the following makes sense:

```
resources :events, params: :token || :id
```

Backstory:
I am setting up a "sharing link" so users without an account can view an events page, similar to google docs. To do this, a unique token is generated for each event, creating a websafe url ([Protected sharing link in Ruby on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25133637/protected-sharing-link-in-ruby-on-rails)). The issue I am facing is trying to maintain routing using both the event_id and the event_token since the event page is also being viewed by account holders, where finding events by id is much easier.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the url is the same shape -

```
# routes.rb
resources :events

# your urls
/events/15
/events/some-token-string
```

Rails will treat everything after the last slash as the `id` parameter. From there you can just query using an `or` clause

```
# Rails 5 with no raw SQL
Event.where(id: params[:id]).or(Event.where(token: params[:id])).first

# Rails 4 and lower (also works with Rails 5)
Event.where("id = ? or token = ?", params[:id], params[:id]).first
```

Comment: exactly what I was looking for, and even simpler in execution. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Can't think of any *built-in* mechanisms, but you could use [`friendly_id`](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) gem to achieve this.