# Route to page based on generated token saved in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm setting up a shared link based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25134349/6769558) with the twist that users can create as many sharing links as they want (and revoke them individually).

The tokens are generated and then saved into a table that has the associated `user_id`, `link` (link = token), and a `note` that users can enter to remember who/what they authorized with this link. All of these links go to the same user page (i.e. the content doesn't change, but you should be able to revoke a specific person's access to that page by deleting their token).

The usual route to find the linked content is `users/:id/profile`. How would I set up the routes to take the token value and map to the right address. It would be great if the public link doesn't expose the user id number (e.g. the link would go to `users/profile/:link`)

Here is the schema for the generated links if it's useful

```
create_table "sharings", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "link"
  t.text     "note"
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_sharings_on_user_id"
end
```

**EDIT**

So the way I am trying to set this up is so that there can be multiple `:link`s mapping to the same place. The way I understand the answer linked above is that it will map only one `:token` to an id. For this I'd like the user to be able to create multiple links (tied together by their `user_id`).

I was thinking something like this, but I get an error `undefined method user_id for #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>`

routes (the first one works, it's the one I'd like to map the second to)

```
get 'users/:id/profile', to: 'users#profile', as: :profile
get 'users/profile/:link', to: 'sharings#shared_profile', as: :shared_profile
```

controller action (I don't know if render is the right way to display, but I'd like to display the page and not redirect to the address with the user id)

```
def shared_profile
  @link = Sharing.where(link: :link)
  @user_id = @link.find(user_id)
  render profile_path(@user_id)
end
```

**EDIT 2**

Here's what I'm thinking. It's also possible that there is a better way to set this up than what I've done.

[image]

Comment: It is pretty much covered in the link you provided.

Comment: I could be wrong, but my understanding of that solution is that only one ID is linked to the token. I edited the answer to try to add some more detail about what I want to do and the code I have so far.

Comment: Ok, no problem, I didn't read it very thoroughly. I'll have a look at this tonight if nobody has answered by then.

Comment: So what you want is - a user can share a resource to multiple users with a link specific to each user ? and the same resource could be shared with multiple people with multiple links ? Am I right ?

Comment: Right, the resource is singular (always), but the links can be multiple. If the user wants to generate only 1 link and share it with everyone they can or they can create and shared multiple links for different users (but they all map to the same resource). The core `users/:id/profile` will remain private (only the correct logged in user can see this) even though all the links are actually mapping to this.