# Creating unique Token for link that can only be accessed with the said link?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, random

**Issue**: I have an order confirmation page once orders are placed.  The route loks like this:

```
resources :orders do
      get 'order_confirmation', :on => :member
  end
```

**The link**:

```
example.com/orders/1001/order_confirmation
```

**Instead**, I would like to generate a unique link like this:

```
example.com/orders/1001/order_confirmation/79sa9182-sd9871234123456f
```

So if someone makes an order for order 1002, they can't go "hey let me see what order 1001 made".

BTW, the **order_confirmation** is within the OrdersController **like this**:

```
  def order_confirmation
    @order = Order.find(params[:id])
  end
```

I do have security with this for users who are signed in with CanCanCan, but I made this order_confirmation page for people who do not create accounts and probably won't ever create an account.

**How can I accomplish this so a link like:**

```
example.com/orders/1001/order_confirmation/79sa9182-sd9871234123456f
```

**Is generated for order confirmations, and links like this:**

```
example.com/orders/1001/order_confirmation/
```

cannot be accessed by anyone, even the purchaser?

---

I did find this: [Protected sharing link in Ruby on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25133637/protected-sharing-link-in-ruby-on-rails)

But I am not sure how I would apply this for the order confirmation page since it doesn't have it's own table or model.  It's already in the OrdersController

Comment: It's not a good idea to display incremental id in such urls in any case. You can use friendly_id gem, generate uuid-like slug for orders and use it instead of id in urls. Or completely replace order id with uuid

Comment: If the page is only accessible by "guest" users, then I question its purpose in the return journey... Why not make the page viewable *once*; provide the option to email a receipt of purchase; but don't allow a second view (or viewing after a short period of time) of the public URL containing order details? That seems like a much safer option to me.

Comment: For example, even if the URL is really obscure, you could leak private details of anyone accessing it on a public computer.

Comment: @Vasilisa What would be the benefit for using friendly_id vs creating a random token with SecureRandom and finding by token instead of id?  But I see what you're saying and it's making me think i should just use token (or slug if i use friendly_id gem) and then i wouldn't need to worry about access for the order id as the ID would be very random - then the url can be for example :  example.com/orders/1234123adsff-32451/order-confirmation

Comment: @TomLord Sorry if I was vague in my explanation but the order_confirmation page can be seen by anyone, as of now, who creates an order.  If the user is signed in there will be a link for them to navigate to their dashboard.  The order confirmation page is somewhat needed to stick around for convenience.  Shopify has a similar system but i notice they have 2 id tokens for a link sort of like this: example.com/orders/23415dfgsd43/confirmation/324sadfq123a   --- i am wondering how they achieve this.

Comment: @Vasilisa after looking over the friendly_id documentation.  I don't see much about the UUID unique token.  I do see a few things on it but mostly in the case where there are two of the same entries in 1 model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved the to_param issue. I just simply removed it and reorganized the routes for the specific member route.....

When using:

`resources :orders, param: :order_token do
      get 'order_confirmation', :on => :member
  end`

In my routes, I am able to go to the URL i want. Although, after an order is created, it still directs me to a route using the :id.

I then change my redirect to:

`redirect_to order_confirmation_order_path(@order.order_token)`

And it works.

I also removed my `to_param` override.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that `79sa9182-sd9871234123456f` is code or something else you store somewhere.

Then you need to modify your routes like this:

```
resources :orders do
  get 'order_confirmation/:code' => 'orders#order_confirmation', :on => :member
end
```

Then you can create a link to order confirmation page with your new path, for example:

```
your_new_path(id: <order_id>, code: <your_code>)
```

Comment: The code was a random entry as if I used SecureRandom - it was an example.  But @vasilla may have put me on the right path.  Using SecureRandom will most likely solve my problem.  Although, I would like SecureRandom to be generated for both the order and the order_confirmation but i will need to toggle around to figure that out!

Comment: I was thinking.  With this I could technically create 2 tokens on an order creation.  One for the Order (used as the ID), and one for the Confirmation.  And then create a URL for example, domain.com/orders/13523f3a534/order_confirmation/2352df23452 --- which would be domain.com/orders/:id_token/order_confirmation/:confirmation_token ?

Answer (score 0):

The benefit for using friendly_id - all works out of the box. If you add `use: [:slugged, :finders]` to the model, you don't need to care what to use - id or slug. Both options work:

```
Order.find(1)
Order.find('my_first_order')
```

Generating uuids with friendly_id is not very common practice, I used it since we already had the gem in our project. It looks like:

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :blank_string, use: [:slugged, :finders]

  private

  def blank_string
    ''
  end
end
```

If you don't need slugs for other model it would be easier to add new `token` column to the orders table with a default value `default: 'uuid_generate_v4()'` and index on the column. Don't forget to enable extension 'uuid-ossp'.

And here is a [good article](https://tomharrisonjr.com/uuid-or-guid-as-primary-keys-be-careful-7b2aa3dcb439) about pros and cons of uuids as primary keys. In short it says: "Best of Both? Integers Internal, UUIDs External"

Comment: So, would this work well with tokens? Because i have implemented a token on order create, used to_param to over ID and now i'm having issues elsewhere because of the override.  I want to be able to, as you're saying, find records with more than one column

Comment: I ended up figuring my situation out.  thanks for the help tho.  i will create an answer son after some testing